# WhereHasMorph query doesn't work with custom morph types

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using different allies for morph Relations with `morphMap()`. When I use `WhereHasMorph()` and give my custom morph type, it doesn't work.

in Controller :

```
 $data = Product::whereHasMorph(
            'productable',
            ['PrintedBook'], // Book::class
            function (Builder $query, $type) use($title){
                $query->where('title', 'LIKE', "{$title}%");
            }
        )->get();
```

and in `Book` model :

```
    public function getMorphClass () {
        return $this->morphClass ?: 'Book'; // in query it uses 'Book' instead of 'PrintedBook'
    }

    public function product()
    {
        $this->morphClass = 'PrintedBook';
        return $this->morphOne('App\Models\Product', 'productable');
    }
```

and `morphMap` :

```
Relation::morphMap([
            'PrintedBook' => Book::class,
            // ...
        ]);
```

So are there any ways to solve this?
Thanks.

[related issue posted on github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/29181)

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Also, how come you have two aliases for one model?

Comment: laravel 8.x . I switch between them with `$this->morphClass = '...' before declaring relation.`

Comment: Please, add more information about your problem, what is your version of Laravel etc..